# How can I upload a List<Class> to cloud firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

my flutter app has a class "Cart" which has one string value i.e name of order, and one is an int value which is the quantity of order. When I add an item to cart, it will be added to a List (using provider) so how can I upload that List to firestore.

Comment: You can't store Dart objects in Firestore. You can store these data types: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Comment: @JoãoSoares no, I'm dropping that idea to upload a class

Answer (score 2):

You can have methods in your class to transform to and from a Map and then store the JSON string in Firestore:

```
class Cart{
  String name;
  int quantity;

  Cart({
    this.name,
    this.quantity,
  });

  Cart.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) :
    name = map['name'],
    quantity = map['quantity'];

  Map toMap(){
    return {
      'name': name,
      'quantity': quantity,
    };
  }
}
```

Then you can encode the results of the methods to JSON:

```
json.encode(Cart.toMap());

Cart.fromMap(json.decode(cartStringFromFirestore))
```

Comment: @HassanAnsari I'm glad I could help you. If the answer worked, please mark it as correct, and consider up voting for visibility.